# CSS Animation End go to URL

Tags: javascript, css, animation, webkit

How would I set up an event listener to detect a CSS animation end - and go to either a new URL, or alternatively another div on the same page.

Comment: `element.addEventListener('transitionend', callback, false);`

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript how would I incorporate this into the page from... script tag to close script tag, Thank you for your help.. my apologies if this is baby step stuff...